QT setMask does not working when QBitmap cover entire widget
The mask does not work with QRect(0, 0, ui->widget->width(), ui->widget->height().
QBitmap windowMask(ui->widget->width(), ui->widget->height());
windowMask.fill(Qt::transparent);
QPainter p(&windowMask);
// 
p.fillRect(QRectF(0, 0, ui->widget->width(), ui->widget->height()), Qt::white);
p.end();
ui->widget->setMask(windowMask);


But it work fine with 1px more
p.fillRect(QRectF(1, 1, ui->widget->width(), ui->widget->height()), Qt::white);


How do I cover the entire widget?

From the documentation: "Use the QColor objects Qt::color0 and Qt::color1 when drawing on a QBitmap object" and "Note that using the Qt::black and Qt::white colors make no sense because the QColor::pixel() value is not necessarily 0 for black and 1 for white".

Also: 1. since QBitmap is 1-bit depth, using fill(Qt::transparent) is inappropriate, and it should be Qt::color0; 2. there is no point in setting a mask that covers the whole widget area, just use clearMask() in that case; 3. if you're just using rectangular shapes and they always start in the origin point (the top left corner, aka 0, 0), you don't need to use QPainter at all, just create the bitmap with the target size and fill it with color1.
